# ASP .NET Core Identity SignInManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

Good day. ASP.NET-Core project was with out authentication. So, I tried to add built-in Identity for this purpose. Tables in database successfully created, new user registered. In Account controller in Login Method `SignInManager` return success in process. In partial view, where links for Login\Register added injection and library (all looks as default project with authentication, based on its implementation):

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
```

Then in view checking:

```
SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)
```

After Login it's always false, irrelevant moment ago state for login in controller was success. Have I missed to add something at `Configuration` in `Startup.cs` or some else? Implemented all things as in default VS project with authentication.

Upd. Configuration in `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseMySql("Server=; Database=; Uid=;Pwd=;"));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;

            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;

            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Here added my application services. 
        .......

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you show Configuration of auth in your Startup.cs?

Comment: Upd - add config in startup.cs

Comment: I think you forgot use Cookie settings see -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore2x#cookie-settings

Comment: Thanks, uopeydel! Look it`s working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your ConfigureServices method configure cookies as well. Something like below:

```
...
// Here added my application services. 
.......
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => 
{
     options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
     options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(5);
     options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but after checking your post, I realised I haven't included the authentication. I didn't need to set my cookies.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // ...

    app.UseAuthentication();

    // ...
}
```

I thought I'll answer this question in case someone else comes across it having faced the same problem.