# Why is my Login not working for my mvc web app

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

**So I have a login action that uses signInManager but everytime I try to log in it redirects me back to the login page.

Here is my controller code**

```
  [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var res = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password,false,false);
                if (res.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }

                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Login");


            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

Here is the html

```
<form role="form" asp-action="Login" asp-controller="Account" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Email">User Name</label>
                    <input type="email" name="Email" asp-for="Email" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Email Address">
                    <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="Password" asp-for="Password" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Password">
                    <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-info btn-block">

            </form>
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging?

Comment: Maybe you forgot use Cookie settings,see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49571713/asp-net-core-identity-signinmanager